# double quotes not dispalying in the edit page

Tags: php, html

I have this piece of code in my html.the field may contain special characters.

```
<tr id="p2" >
      <td><strong>Tussenvoegsel:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="familyname" width="120"></td>
    </tr>
```

In the backend i am correctly getting the value of the fields and the special characters(double quotes also) are also properly inserted into the corresponding column of the table.

```
$familyname=JRequest::getVar('familyname');
$familyname=str_replace("\'","'","$familyname");
$familyname=str_replace("'","\'","$familyname");
```

My problem is when i go to the edit page of the form all the special character are showing correctly in the field but double quote is not showing at all(Note:in the database the column as double quotes also).What i am missing?

Comment: In your snippet you have two calls to `str_replace()`. The first replaces `\'` with `'`, but the second swaps them back. Why?

Comment: @MikeW to avoid the accidental insert of '\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that something like:

```
<input type="text" value="my value "with" quotes">
```

Generates invalid HTML cause of the double quotes of the value inside the double quotes of the attribute value. (As you see in the highlighting above.)

So you have to escape the double quotes for `input` tags. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Double quotes in `textareas` are no problem cause the content is between the opening and the closing tag and not in an attribute.

```
<textarea>Here are "double quotes" okay and have not to be escaped</textarea>
```